# Will I be able to turn my ubuntu touch phone into a desktop pc?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

If I recall correctly one of the advertised features of Ubuntu phones was the ability to turn it into a full fledged ubuntu desktop when docked into a station with external keyboard and monitor.

Now that the first devices are out, and this feature is nowhere to be found,I was wondering if it's in Canonical's plans to add it when ubuntu touch and ubuntu desktop finally converge into the same os.

Needless to say it would be a killing feature, for me at least.

Answer (score 2):

Today's article on BBC says No, not yet:

http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-31148661